# PHP - Exibir GIF Animado

Tags: php, imagick

Olá, estou com uma certa dificuldade em exibir GIF Animado em meu script, sei que a biblioteca GD não exibe GIF animado, gostaria de saber como faço isso.

Apenas quero enviar a GIF Animada de uma URL para o browser, exemplo:

```
//As Funções são apenas para ilustração

$GIF = Pegar_GIF_Animado('url.gif');
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
Exibir_GIF($GIF);
```

Obrigado!

Comment: será feita alguma manipulação na imagem ou é somente para exibir?

Comment: Somente pra exibir

Answer (score 1):

Somente para exibir não é necessário utilizar nenhuma biblioteca. Basta enviar um cabeçalho HTTP e ler o arquivo da imagem com [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readfile.php).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
readfile('url.gif');
```

Comment: Nossa rsrs, muito o brigado, deu certo! Eu estava usando o imagegif(), ai ele não ficava animado, só aparecia o 1º frame.